# How Do I Protect Documents In Restricted Access Pages?

Tags: typo3

I have implemented Protected pages in typo3 successfully but the documents (like pdf, ppt) linked with in that protected pages were accessible directly without login.

How do I protect it as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose you may want to use the TYPO3 extension [naw_securedl](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/naw_securedl/current/).

Comment: I am facing one more problem, When i try to download the file by direct url, it works. I want to deny that also. How could i achieve that please. ?

Comment: As described in the [manual](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/naw_securedl/current/info/?tx_terfe_pi1%5BdownloadFile%5D=doc%252Fmanual.sxw&cHash=785089c19f) you have to put a .htaccess file in the directory that you want to protect. See the example files in the /res folder of the extension.